# How to only show the rest of the data columns after excluding common data columns

Tags: sql, sas

There are exam two tables.

I'd like to show the rest of data columns that excluded common data comparing two tables between A table and B table using ' where t1.STU_ID = t2.STU_ID condition'.

But there is the problem in my sas query(proc sql) code. let me know how to solve.

- Exam two tables

  1. A table

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2002123 | A120 |
| 456 | 2002456 | A120 |
| 789 | 2002789 | A120 |
| 134 | 2002134 | A120 |
| 135 | 2002135 | A120 |

2. B table

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2002123 | A120 |
| 456 | 2002456 | A120 |
| 789 | 2002789 | A120 |

- Expected result

| STU_ID | STU_KEY | STU_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | 2002134 | A120 |
| 135 | 2002135 | A120 |

```
  '''problem code'''
  PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE ab.table AS
  SELECT t1.STU_ID, t1.STU_KEY, t1.STU_CODE
  FROM STU.A_table as t1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT t2.STU_ID, t2.STU_KEY, t2.STU_CODE
  FROM STU.B_table as t2;
  QUIT;
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use SQL instead of basic SAS statements?

Comment: `MINUS` is not a standard SQL keyword.  Did you mean `EXCEPT`?

Comment: @Tom 
1) I will use SAS proc sql. 
2) I'd like to use 'EXCEPT'.

Comment: @Plutos, Your query with `EXCEPT` seems working fine. It does give expected result. What is your need?

Comment: @Plutos Your code produces exactly the results you want in SAS.

Comment: @Arun Dec I already solved above problem using 'NOT IN' statement. Thank you.

Comment: @StuSztukowski I already solved above problem using 'NOT IN' statement. Thank you.